# AttributeError: module 'MyLib' has no attribute 'add'

Tags: python

I'm not too sure why i keep getting the error "AttributeError: module 'MyLib' has no attribute 'add'" since it looks to me like I have already defined "add" in my MyLib file. I definitely am likely missing something obvious but was hoping to get some assistance on it.

```
import MyLib
while True: 
  lowrange = input("Enter your Lower range --> ")
  highrange = input("Enter your Higher range --> ")
  try: #Exception to catch inputs that are not numbers on range.
    lowrange = float(lowrange)
    highrange = float(highrange)
  except Exception:
    print ("Please enter a number")
    continue
      
  #limit input
  while True: 
    num1 = input("Enter first number --> ")
    try:#Catch inputs that are not numbers for calculations.
      num1 = float(num1)
    except Exception:
      print ("Please enter a number")
      continue
    if lowrange > num1 or highrange < num1:#Range limit
       print ("Input number not in defined range. Please check the numbers and try again.")
    else:
      break
  while True:
    num2 = input("Enter second number --> ")
    try:#Catch inputs that are not numbers for calculations.
      num2 = float(num2)
    except Exception:
      print ("Please enter a number")
      continue
    if lowrange > num2 or highrange < num2:#Range limit
       print ("Input number not in defined range. Please check the numbers and try again.")  
    else:
      prob1 = str(input("Enter a problem in the following format, Num1,Num2,operator.(+,-,*,/)"))
      break
    
 
# Results
  print (num1, "+", num2, "=", MyLib.add(num1, num2))
  print (num1, "-", num2, "=", MyLib.sub(num1, num2))
  print (num1, "*", num2, "=", MyLib.mult(num1, num2))
  print (num1, "/", num2, "=", MyLib.div(num1, num2))
  print("The answer to your problem is ", Mylib.scalc(prob1))
  ans=input(' Do you want to preform another calculation? Enter "y" to continue.')
  if (ans=="y"):
     continue
  else:
     print("Thanks for using my calculator")
     break
```

This is the code for the MyLib function where we were supposed to "1) Move all the functions into Mylib.py
2) Use import to include Mylib into the code
3) Test the code and make sure that the prior code is still working
4) Add the following function into Mylib"

```
#Define the main program function
def main():
    #Define input function
    def float_input(msg):
        while True:
            try:
                return float(input(msg))
            except ValueError:
                print("You must enter a valid number.")
            else:
                break
    #Declare variables
    lowrange=float_input("What is your low range?")
    highrange=float_input("What is your high range?")
    num1=float_input ("What is your first number?")
    num2=float_input ("What is your second number?")

    #Defining the calculations
    def add (num1, num2):
        sum = (num1 + num2)
        print ("The result of", num1, "+", num2, "=", sum)
    def sub (num1, num2):
        diff = num1 - num2
        print ("The result of", num1, "-", num2, "=", diff)
    def muilt (num1, num2):
        prod = num1 * num2
        print ("The result of", num1, "*", num2, "=", prod)
    def div (num1, num2):
        if num2 ==0:
            print ("You cannot divide by 0")
        else:
            quot = num1 / num2
            print ("The result of", num1, "/", num2, "=", quot)
    #if/else
    if num1 < lowrange or num1 > highrange or num2 < lowrange or num2 > highrange:
        print ("The input values are outside ranges, please check the numbers and try again!")
    else:
        #Calling the calcs
        add(num1, num2)
        sub(num1, num2)
        mult(num1, num2)
        div(num1, num2)
        print("Thanks for using my calculator")

    def scalc(p1):
        astring = p1.split(",")
        print(astring)
        num1 = float(astring[0])
        num2 =  float(astring[1])
        if astring[2]=="+":
            add(num1,num2)
        elif astring[2] =="-":
            sub(num1, num2)
        elif astring[2] == "*":
            mult(num1, num2)
        elif astring [2] == "/":
            div(num1,num2)
        return value

    p1 = input ("Enter two numbers and an operator seperated by a comma: ")
    scalc(p1)
```

Comment: In your mylib file you have defined everything inside main function. That is why you are not able to access it. You should write the function outside the main if you want to call the functions from outside that main function

Comment: Is there a reason why you have, for example, `lowrange` defined in both codes?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it should be all functional, the `add` function is not part of `MyLib` but a function called `main`. Thus, when you call `MyLib`, it does not know about `add`. It only knows about `main`. You have nested functions within functions. What you should do is remove the tab indentation so that `add`, `sub`, `multi`, etc. is not indented much like `main`. However, that will not work entirely because below your `div` function, you have uses of variables set in `main`.

There are two ways to fix this. Belhadjer Samir suggested a functional approach. I would suggest an object-oriented approach. Specifically, what you probably want is a class called `MyLib` (`def main() -> class MyLib`. You will then want to import it as: `from mylib import MyLib` (i.e. rename the file from MyLib.py to mylib.py - see below for why). You will want to initialize it somewhere in your other code (`ml = MyLib()`).

Then you can use the `add`, `subtract` methods.

Note: PEP8 rules say to use lower case for modules (`mylib` for mylib.py) and classes as CamelCase (e.g., `MyLib`).

Comment: I've been trying to use your suggestion and rewrite it, but I can't seem to get it to work, could you give me an example?

Comment: This is a quick response. I can dig out something better later today. The Python docs explain classes and how to use it here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects

Comment: @chrismove if you do want to move to OOP for this exercise, I can work to re-write what you have. It is a bit of an overhaul and I'll just need to use my IDE. Not sure if you saw my other question about the multiple variable definition in your script. You don't seem to use `main` for its input()`. Any reason why?

Comment: No I do not have a specific reason, this is for a homework assignment that I can't seem to grasp and the teacher is being fairly useless on assistance so I figured I would turn here. My only real parameters are:

Comment: 1) Move all the functions into Mylib.py
2) Use import to include Mylib into the code
3) Test the code and make sure that the prior code is still working
4) Add the following function into Mylib
scalc(p1)
p1 will be a string like this "N1, N2, operator"
use string functions to parse the first number, the second number, and the operator from the input string.
use the prior functions (add, subtract, divide, and multiply ) to do the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

you have to import you module like this :

```
from MyLib import main as MyLib
```

this is because all your code in Mylib is in main function